# Hive sql select different user_id from multi partitions

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Here is a hive table

```
create table user_log (user_id string, visit_tm bigint) partition by(etl_dt string);

etl_dt >= '2018-01-01' and etl_dt <= '2018-01-30'
```

Every partition has lots of records.AND I want to select 100 user_id from every partition and every user_id is different with each other.
How to write the Hive sql? I need some help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query:

```
select DISTINCT user_id from  user_log where etl_dt >= '2018-01-01' limit 100 UNION select DISTINCT user_id from  user_log where etl_dt <= '2018-01-01' limit 100;
```

hope this help